# Include module position if cookie value is set

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.4, jquery, cookies

When users visit a page on my site, I've written code to set a value:

```
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("promotionpage") > -1) {
    Cookies.set('landingpage', 'kent', { expires: 30, path: '/promotionpage' });
}
```

This is working great and the cookie is being set. Depending on if the above cookie is set, I want to then add a module position to the index.php page, I've written the following to read if the cookie is set and then include a module position, but it's not working:

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE['kent'])){ ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="kentModal" style="none" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: are you trying to show the module on the same page as where you set the cookie or on subsequent pages

Comment: I'm trying to load it on subsequent pages once the cookie has been set.

Answer (score 2):

You set the cookie via JS with name: `landingpage` 
BUT you checking in PHP for a cookie name: `kent`.

Just fix that ;)

Your Cookie-JS-Plugin works like:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you use cookies seems wrong, unless there is a library that you use here.

According to quirksmode you would use something like

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("promotionpage") > -1) {
     document.cookie = 'landingpage=kent; expires=<?php echo date('D, j M Y H:i:s', time()+30);?> path=/promotionpage');
}
```

This question has a good list of JavaScript libraries to manage cookies easier https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825683/123594

A couple of other comments:

- You are checking for "promotionpage" to be anywhere in the url, but the cookie is only valid if your path BEGINS WITH "promotionpage"
- Do you want the cookie really only to be valid for 30 seconds?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the cookie is being set correctly already I just can't work out how to read it and display the module position.  For your info, I'm using js.cookie.js from Github here https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Maybe its expired after 30 seconds already? Ignore, I see its in days